# Non tangent through conic passes through two points

Tags: conic-sections

Given a non degenerate conic $C$ and a point $O\in C$. I generate an angle $\theta$ uniformly in $[-\pi,\pi)$. Now I draw a line with slope $\tan \theta$ through $O$. Given that this line is not the tangent to $C$ at $O$, is it true that the line will intersect the curve at one more point (in addition to $O$ ie) with probability $1$ ?

Probability was needed to exclude cases like $C = \{(x,y)|y=x^2\}, O = (0,0), \theta = \pi/2$

Comment: for a second degree polynomial it is easy to see as complex roots always come in pairs

Comment: Probably overkill, but do you know Bezout's theorem?  The problem then amounts to showing the other intersection point is the point at infinity with probability 0.

Comment: I do not know Bezout's Theorem, I think I'll try what the other comment is saying

Comment: A line intersects any nondegenerate conic at most twice; there is only one intersection point iff the line is tangent to the conic.

Comment: @amd link to proof?

Comment: It’s a simple consequence of [Bézout’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), but it’s easy enough to prove algebraically for yourself.